# Vb 2008 MDI application getting values from child form

Tags: vb.net

I have on the MDIparent a Save button. My issue is I am on one of the child forms and have filled in all data in textboxes and then I would click the SAVE button on top of my MDI parent. That button checks what is the activechild and calls routine on the form to Insert/Update records in database.
But when I click the save button in debug I see if find the correct child form and code goes where I would it to but all the Txtboxes.text are = ""
Here is the code on the button on MDIParent form.

```
Select Case Me.ActiveMdiChild.Name
    Case "frm1"
       frm1.btnSave_Click(sender, e)
End Select
```

When the case is matched and goes back to frm1 none of the textboxes have values.
I know I am missing something.. any help

Comment: Is 'frm1' the name of your form of the name of the instance of your form?

Comment: Yes it is the activemdichild. It hits the frm1.btnsave_click and goes to that code behind the buttons. However all textboxes on frm1=""

Comment: I am confident it has to be a scope issue. Losing the values when click the save button on mdiparent. I am trying to avoid having every child form having to have their own save button

Comment: What I am thinking is that frm1.btnSave is calling the default instance, and not your instance of frm1. What is the name of your variable that creates the mdi child?